# pandas fill NA but not all based on recent past record

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
stud_name   act_qtr year    yr_qty  qtr mov_avg_full    mov_avg_2qtr_min_period
0   ABC Q2  2014    2014Q2  NaN NaN NaN
1   ABC Q1  2016    2016Q1  Q1  13.0    14.5
2   ABC Q4  2016    2016Q4  NaN NaN NaN
3   ABC Q4  2017    2017Q4  NaN NaN NaN
4   ABC Q4  2020    2020Q4  NaN NaN NaN

OP = pd.read_clipboard()

stud_name   qtr year    t_score p_score yr_qty  mov_avg_full    mov_avg_2qtr_min_period
0   ABC Q1  2014    10  11  2014Q1  10.000000   10.0
1   ABC Q1  2015    11  32  2015Q1  10.500000   10.5
2   ABC Q2  2015    13  45  2015Q2  11.333333   12.0
3   ABC Q3  2015    15  32  2015Q3  12.250000   14.0
4   ABC Q4  2015    17  21  2015Q4  13.200000   16.0
5   ABC Q1  2016    12  56  2016Q1  13.000000   14.5
6   ABC Q2  2017    312 87  2017Q2  55.714286   162.0
7   ABC Q3  2018    24  90  2018Q3  51.750000   168.0

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

I would like to fillna() based on below logic

For ex: let's take `stud_name = ABC`. He has multipple NA records. Let's take his `NA` for `2020Q4`. To fill that, we pick the latest record from `df` for `stud_name=ABC` before `2020Q4`  (which is 2018Q3). Similarly, if we take `stud_name = ABC`. His another `NA` record is for `2014Q2`. We pick the latest (prior) record from `df` for `stud_name=ABC` before `2014Q2` (which is 2014Q1). We need to sort based on `yearqty` values to get the latest (prior) record correctly

We need to do this for each `stud_name` and for a big dataset

So, we fillna in `mov_avg_full` and `mov_avg_2qtr_min_period`

**If there are no previous records to look at in df dataframe, leave NA as it is**

I was trying something like below but it doesn't work and incorrect

```
Filled = OP.merge(df,on=['stud_name'],how='left')
filled.sort_values(['year','Qty'],inplace=True)
filled['mov_avg_full'].fillna(Filled.groupby('stud_name']['mov_avg_full'].shift())
filled['mov_avg_2qtr_min_period'].fillna(Filled .groupby('stud_name']['mov_avg_2qtr_min_period'].shift())
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this post? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you might want to use `append` instead of `merge`. In other words, you want to concatenate vertically instead of horizontally. Then after sorting the DataFrame by `stud_name` and `yr_qtr`, you can use `groupby` and `fillna` methods on it.

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create the sample dataframes
import numpy as np
op = pd.DataFrame({'stud_name': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC'}, 'act_qtr': {0: 'Q2', 1: 'Q1', 2: 'Q4', 3: 'Q4', 4: 'Q4'}, 'year': {0: 2014, 1: 2016, 2: 2016, 3: 2017, 4: 2020}, 'yr_qty': {0: '2014Q2', 1: '2016Q1', 2: '2016Q4', 3: '2017Q4', 4: '2020Q4'}, 'qtr': {0: np.NaN, 1: 'Q1', 2: np.NaN, 3: np.NaN, 4: np.NaN}, 'mov_avg_full': {0: np.NaN, 1: 13.0, 2: np.NaN, 3: np.NaN, 4: np.NaN}, 'mov_avg_2qtr_min_period': {0: np.NaN, 1: 14.5, 2: np.NaN, 3: np.NaN, 4: np.NaN}})
df = pd.DataFrame({'stud_name': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC', 5: 'ABC', 6: 'ABC', 7: 'ABC'}, 'qtr': {0: 'Q1', 1: 'Q1', 2: 'Q2', 3: 'Q3', 4: 'Q4', 5: 'Q1', 6: 'Q2', 7: 'Q3'}, 'year': {0: 2014, 1: 2015, 2: 2015, 3: 2015, 4: 2015, 5: 2016, 6: 2017, 7: 2018}, 't_score': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 13, 3: 15, 4: 17, 5: 12, 6: 312, 7: 24}, 'p_score': {0: 11, 1: 32, 2: 45, 3: 32, 4: 21, 5: 56, 6: 87, 7: 90}, 'yr_qty': {0: '2014Q1', 1: '2015Q1', 2: '2015Q2', 3: '2015Q3', 4: '2015Q4', 5: '2016Q1', 6: '2017Q2', 7: '2018Q3'}, 'mov_avg_full': {0: 10.0, 1: 10.5, 2: 11.333333, 3: 12.25, 4: 13.2, 5: 13.0, 6: 55.714286, 7: 51.75}, 'mov_avg_2qtr_min_period': {0: 10.0, 1: 10.5, 2: 12.0, 3: 14.0, 4: 16.0, 5: 14.5, 6: 162.0, 7: 168.0}})

# Append df to op
dfa = op.append(df[['stud_name', 'yr_qty', 'mov_avg_full', 'mov_avg_2qtr_min_period']])

# Sort before applying fillna
dfa = dfa.sort_values(['stud_name', 'yr_qty'])

# Group by stud_name and apply ffill
dfa[['mov_avg_full', 'mov_avg_2qtr_min_period']] = dfa.groupby('stud_name')[['mov_avg_full', 'mov_avg_2qtr_min_period']].fillna(method='ffill')

# Extract the orginal rows from op and deal with columns
dfa = dfa[dfa.act_qtr.notna()].drop('qtr', axis=1)

print(dfa)
```

### Output:

| stud_name | act_qtr | year | yr_qty | mov_avg_full | mov_avg_2qtr_min_period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Q2 | 2014 | 2014Q2 | 10 | 10 |
| ABC | Q1 | 2016 | 2016Q1 | 13 | 14.5 |
| ABC | Q4 | 2016 | 2016Q4 | 13 | 14.5 |
| ABC | Q4 | 2017 | 2017Q4 | 55.7143 | 162 |
| ABC | Q4 | 2020 | 2020Q4 | 51.75 | 168 |

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. May I know how do you generare the code for your sample datafrane? Did you manually write it? Or is there any automated way to get the code of datafrane based on dataframe?

Comment: shouldn't we do 'bfill'? Because, when it is 2014Q2 (with NA value), we should look at the recent past (whatever it is for that subject). Let's consoder it is 2014Q1, in this case, isn't it bfill?

Comment: You're welcome:) In this case, after using `pd.read_clipboard()`, I generated `dict` by using `op.to_dict()` and `df.to_dict()`. Then I copied the output text of those dictionaries, I and used `pd.DataFrame()` method.

Comment: I think you need `ffill` not `bfill` because you want to copy `2018Q3` data to `2020Q4` on the dataframe which is sorted by `stud_name` and `yr_qty`. In other word, you want to copy forward in terms of time series.

Comment: fantastic work btw. I thought this would be really complicated but your solution makes it easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you. Vertical concatenation sometimes drastically simplifies problems and gives you a straightforward solution. Good luck with your project:)